# Cannot start some containers after restarting docker daemon

Tags: docker

When I restart docker service, I would start the following container, but error occurs.

```
$docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE               COMMAND      CREATED       STATUS
591009977bae  yomin/deepdive:1.0  "/bin/bash"  3 weeks ago   Exited (-1) 3 hours ago
```

Error:

```
$docker start -i -a 591009977bae
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 591009977bae: [0] Id already in use: Container with id exists: 591009977baefe0ad7986b3149e9c8090655c3419b46e72bfa0c554189a54739
```

The following is some info, server is Ubuntu14.04:

```
$docker info
Containers: 6
Images: 60
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 76
Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-24-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 24
Total Memory: 94.37 GiB
Name: ubuntu
ID: P322:L4XK:BGEL:AAZ4:O6VF:IX2O:AUMK:QCBD:RJIS:RGOU:LCJI:GDGU
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

It seems different from other issues I found on Stackoverflow...Could anyone help me?

Comment: May be [this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11432) issue...?

Comment: Well, In my /var/lib/docker/execdriver/native/ directory, it's an empty directory.....but still the same error...anyway thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In fact when I reproduce your situation,
I restart the container successfully.

`Docker version 1.9.x` has some **obscure bugs**.

I think it a good idea that you may upgrade your docker-engine to the latest `version(1.10.3)` and retry.